# Should the maintenance template be used when the database API raises an exception?

Tags: 8, maintenance-mode

I have created a maintenance-page.html.twig template for my site.

The settings.php file says:

> This applies when the site is explicitly set to maintenance mode through the administration page **or when the database is inactive due to an error**.

However, on my site, this only works if I explicitly turn on maintenance mode. If I intentionally break access to my database by changing the password I get a page with a PDO error, not my maintenance page.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be the case of where the documentation is out-of-date. That comment has been around verbatim since D7. D8 doesn't produce a themed maintenance page like D7.

When looking at [`_drupal_log_error()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21errors.inc/function/_drupal_log_error/8.1.x), you can see that unless Drupal is going through the install process, a fatal error will output a bare error message with a 500 status then exit:

```
if ($fatal) {
  // We fallback to a maintenance page at this point, because the page generation
  // itself can generate errors.
  // Should not translate the string to avoid errors producing more errors.
  $message = 'The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.' . '<br />' . $message;

  if ($is_installer) {
    // install_display_output() prints the output and ends script execution.
    $output = array(
      '#title' => 'Error',
      '#markup' => $message,
    );
    install_display_output($output, $GLOBALS['install_state'], $response->headers->all());
    exit;
  }

  $response->setContent($message);
  $response->setStatusCode(500, '500 Service unavailable (with message)');

  $response->send();
  // An exception must halt script execution.
  exit;
}
```

Whereas in D7, [`_drupal_log_error()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21errors.inc/function/_drupal_log_error/7.x) passes through a themed maintenance page:

```
if ($fatal) {
  drupal_set_title(t('Error'));
  // We fallback to a maintenance page at this point, because the page generation
  // itself can generate errors.
  print theme('maintenance_page', array('content' => t('The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.')));
  exit;
}
```

Comment: So has the option to supply your own offline template been removed in Drupal 8? If my database fails I'd rather my users see a maintenance page than a PDO error

Comment: Correct, I added the D7 fatal error handling code for clarity.